# Google-cloud + Node, grpc error

Tags: node.js, electron, grpc

I am creating a sample desktop application using electron framework. When i include google-cloud node library in application i got this error.

> Uncaught Error:
>   /home/user/Desktop/projects/sample_desktop_app/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/grpc_node.node:
>   undefined symbol: GENERAL_NAME_free

OS: Ubuntu

Node Version: v7.10.0

Your help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Grpc id a native module that also is not officially supported for electron. This is because native modules are generally hard with electron as they need special treatment or recompilation for the respective platform.

Best way is to follow this thread https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/6138 but you are more or less on your own with it. I would try to have your own backend and proxy grpc calls.